# Windows XP File Properties Security Tab

Tags: security, windows-xp, file-sharing

This is hopefully a real easy one.

In Windows XP on some environments the File Properties dialog (that opens on right-click > properties when viewing the file in windows explorer) sometimes shows a Security Tab and sometimes not.

How does one enable it? (I need to allow "run" access on certain types)

***Note 1:*** I'm logged in with Administrator privileges

***Note 2:*** I'm running NTFS on both machines

***Note 3:*** Running XP Professional on both machines

PS I found one source Googling that suggests this will work but I didn't have any luck;

> ***UPDATE:*** [After 2 reboots](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gt9j80Jkc_A)... based on the 5 steps below... the Security Tab **did** appear.

1. Launch Windows Explorer or My Computer.
2. Click on the Tools at the menu bar, then click on Folder Options.
3. Click on View tab.
4. In the Advanced Settings section at the bottom of the list, uncheck and unselect (clear the tick) on the “Use simple file sharing (Recommended)” check box.
5. Click OK.

(I've linked to two screenshots found on the web of the dialog I'm talking about)

[Without Security Tab](http://www.linglom.com/images/Windows/Tips/Missing-Security-Tab/1.png)

[With Security Tab](http://static.asp.net/asp.net/images/whitepapers/whitepaper3-18.jpg)

Comment: There is a security tab in both of those screenshots.

Comment: As Jeff points out, there is a Security tab on both screenshots. Also, one seems to be properties on a file, whole the other is on a folder (hence the extra tabs on the folder properties one).

Comment: Wow don't I feel like a tool... uhm... I'll update that link

Answer (score 3):

There are two parts to it:

1) If you are running XP Pro - disable simple file sharing. This will make it appear.

2) If you are running XP Home - log in through safe mode, and then the security tab will appear. There is no way in XP Home to get the security tab to appear booted into normal mode that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on the version of Windows XP you are running.  I believe only XP Professional uses the security tab.  I know for certain that Home does not have it.  There are hacks (you can search google for it) to make it appear on the Home edition.

Comment: Good point, I'll update that as a known item...

Answer (score 0):

You have to have Simple File Sharing turned off for the tab to show.

Answer (score 0):

Found this via google:

> If you’re still having problem to reveal or display the Security tab on files or folder properties, check out the following registry hack and set the value to 0 or simply delete the key:
>
> Hive: HKEY_CURRENT_USER
>   Key: Software\Microsoft\windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
>   Name: Nosecuritytab
>   Type: REG_DWORD
>   Value: 1